# VBA Pass Form Controls to Function

Tags: excel, vba

All,

I have been struggling with this for a while: is it possible to pass an object to a function?

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

1. Get the name of which control was pressed on a form (as object?)
2. Send the control's name to function "MyFunction" (as reference?)
3. Disable that same control on "MyFunction"

Called from **form1**:

```
Private Sub button1_Click()
    Dim caller As String
    caller = Form1.ActiveControl.Name

    MyFunction(caller)

End Sub 'I'm able to pass it as a string
```

**button1_Click** calls **MyFunction** and passes **caller** to it:

```
Private Sub MyFunction(caller As String)
    caller.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

I understand this will not work as a **string**. How could I possibly do it as an actual **object**?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is little problem passing an object to a sub:

```
Private Sub Disable(c As Control)
    MsgBox c.Name
    c.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Disable CommandButton1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Disable CommandButton2
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Disable CommandButton3
End Sub
```

In the above I created  a userform with three buttons, they say who they are when clicked and are then disabled.

Note that

```
Disable CommandButton1
```

can be replaced by

```
Disable Me.ActiveControl
```

or even just

```
Disable ActiveControl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even use Variant like so (rough example):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    EnableDisable ActiveControl, "disable"
End Sub

Private Sub EnableDisable(control As Variant, status As String)
    If status = "enabled" Then
        control.Enabled = True
    Else
        control.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

John Coleman's example is better than mine, though.